# Which package to use for using GPIOs on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: go, raspberry-pi, gpio

How can I read the temperature sensor values on GPIO of a Raspberry Pi using the go language?

Please, anyone help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The one that is used with modern kernel ABIs, so `gpiod` by Kent.

Answer (score 5):

Check out Dave Cheney's package:

- https://github.com/davecheney/gpio

There's a classical [blink example](https://github.com/davecheney/gpio/blob/master/examples/blink/blink.go) there.

Comment: This repository [is no longer actively maintained](https://github.com/davecheney/gpio/issues/21#issuecomment-158212861).

Answer (score 3):

http://embd.kidoman.io/

this is a slightly higher level abstraction than dave cheney's gpio library.

In addition to a gpio api, there is support for many common sensors

not sure what your sensor is, but e.g. here is an example for the [bmp180 barometric sensor](https://github.com/kidoman/embd/blob/master/samples/bmp180.go)

Comment: Many common sensors are supported by Linux kernel and there is need to reinvent a (often buggy) wheel.

Comment: @0andriy: Am I correct in assuming you meant "there is [no] need to reinvent..."?

Comment: @MatthewRankin, yes. Sorry for typo.

Answer (score 3):

I have created an extremely simple package for interacting with the GPIO pins on a Raspberry Pi:

https://github.com/nathan-osman/go-rpigpio

A simple program that makes pin 2 flash ten times would look something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/nathan-osman/go-rpigpio"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    p, err := rpi.OpenPin(2, rpi.OUT)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer p.Close()

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        p.Write(rpi.HIGH)
        time.Sleep(300 * time.Millisecond)
        p.Write(rpi.LOW)
        time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    }
}
```

More documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/nathan-osman/go-rpigpio).

Comment: I don't know why but no one elses gpio library worked but yours. thanks so much!

Comment: @Loran this is weird, the `gpiod` by Kent should work the best.

Comment: It’s nice, but not portable.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few Go modules to access the GPIO pins on a Raspberry Pi. However, not all of them are regularly maintained. The table below summarizes some of the available Go modules as of August 11, 2023. The table is sorted by last commit date.

| Module | Stars | Last Commit | License | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [hybridgroup/gobot](https://github.com/hybridgroup/gobot) | 8.4k | Jul 2023 | Apache2 | Framework for robotics/IoT |
| [warthog618/gpiod](https://github.com/warthog618/gpiod) | 321 | Jul 2023 | MIT |  |
| [periph/conn](https://github.com/periph/conn) | 48 | Apr 2023 | Apache-2.0 | Part of [periph](https://periph.io/) library |
| [warthog618/gpio](https://github.com/warthog618/gpio) | 114 | Dec 2022 | MIT | Relies on sysfs which is deprecated |
| [stianeikeland/go-rpio](https://github.com/stianeikeland/go-rpio) | 2k | Dec 2021 | MIT |  |
| [mrmorphic/hwio](https://github.com/mrmorphic/hwio) | 322 | May 2018 | BSD-3 |  |
| [kidoman/embd](https://github.com/kidoman/embd/) | 1.3k | May 2017 | MIT |  |
| [nathan-osman/go-rpigpio](https://github.com/nathan-osman/go-rpigpio) | 64 | Jun 2016 | MIT |  |
| [luismesas/goPi](https://github.com/luismesas/goPi) | 74 | Apr 2014 | MIT |  |

Reading a temperature sensor depends not just on the chosen Go module but also on the temperature sensor being used. For instance, you could use the [AM2302 (wired DHT22) temperature-humidity sensor from Adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/393) in which case you could use the [go-dht](https://github.com/MichaelS11/go-dht) module, which provides DHT22, AM2302, and DHT11 interfaces using the [periph](https://periph.io/) driver.

Comment: The Linux kernel maintainers recommend the `gpiod` by Kent (second in the list). Do not forget the portability aspect, which most of *Pi packagers lack of.

Answer (score 0):

Another is **goPi**  - also has support for [piface](http://www.piface.org.uk/products/piface_digital/)

- https://github.com/luismesas/goPi

And the blink examples

- [standard io](https://github.com/luismesas/goPi/blob/master/examples/blink_MCP23S17/blink_MCP23S17.go)
- [piface](https://github.com/luismesas/goPi/blob/master/examples/blink_piface/blink_piface.go)

Comment: Not portable, right?